# Best way to call Rest API presented on the same server

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have a JSON based REST API implemented using PHP that will be called from my mobile app. I have a website deployed on the same server where the REST API existed.
What is the best way to use the existing functionality, is it by sending a cURL request to my API or just by including actual model classes source code and calling those functions?

Answer (score 2):

If they're logically part of the same application, you might consider implementing the functionality of the REST API as a helper function. Then, you can include that function (and whatever model classes it needs) and get the code re-use without the overhead of creating another request.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but my intention is to know what will be the performance degrade by having another request, will it really kills my app performance. I feel comfortable by having the separate service layer.